# Achieving a slick initial transition to 3D transform with parallax effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I've been experimenting with this effect here:

https://codepen.io/PressOnThis/pen/NbmGPR

The idea is there, but you'll notice the initial transition (or lack of, at this point) is blocky when the cursor enters the div. (I've set the background to magenta to highlight those flaws) I've tried a few things so far, like a timeout before it starts indefinitely capturing the mouse position, but I'm still struggling to achieve that slick transition. A CSS transition is obviously useless here, as it needs to capture the mouse position on `mousemove`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to decrease angles of picture rotation depending on progress of picture scaling, check it out: https://codepen.io/pitetsky/pen/qqwOvB.

Sorry for not the most optimal code without comments. That code is a product of little experimenting. So, in a nutshell about what I've did.

It would be the best to multiply `rotateX` and `rotateY` by quotient of progress of pic-center scaling. A tough point is that scaling of pic is made via CSS `transition`.

Since CSS transitions work slighter in browsers than JS animations without special libs, I didn't move scaling of images to JS.

Instead, on every `mouseenter` into a picture I slightly change value of `scaleTransitionProgress` from 0 to 1 during 0.4 secs, same as css transtition length. And similarly from 1 to 0 on `mouseleave`. And then, when tracking `mousemove`, I adjust dampening depending on this value.

Other code serves for the elimination of some problems occured when mouseentering to other picture while previous was still in progress, or when mouseleave was still in progress.

Ask me in case of any questions.

Comment: Genius. Absolutely terrific. Thanks for the help!